# Can we connect Amazon Kendra with Amazon Neptune?

Tags: amazon-kendra

I am looking for options to search my knowledge graph using kendra.

I have found one blog but that requires connecting Neptune using Lambda and APi Gateway. I am looking for a simpler solution.
[1]: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/incorporating-your-enterprise-knowledge-graph-into-amazon-kendra/

Answer (score 0):

Currently Amazon Kendra does not have a connector to directly crawl and index Amazon Neptune graph database (see [1]).

[1] List of Kendra Connectors: https://aws.amazon.com/kendra/connectors/